# Resolving Gem rake task conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add both gems below to my `Gemfile`.

```
ruby-debug-passenger
ruby-debug-ide
```

And they both includes the `rake debug` task, how can I resolve this conflicting name? I wish to keep both gems, since my teammate would like to use an IDE instead.

Comment: I just tried adding them to Gemfile and got no problem...

Answer (score 0):

You could fork one of the gems and change the name of the debug rake task.